# How to spawn player correctly in the correct position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know what else to do. I've done everything from disabling the character controller, then changing the position, then re-enabling the character controller. I have Auto Sync Transforms turned on. I've tried changing transform.position, I've tried changing the character controller position, I've tried everything and nothing works. I'm at my wits end here just trying to move my character from one point to another. Why is this the hardest thing I've done?

The code instantiates my characters correctly when it wants to. Sometimes they spawn off the map or in some random position way off from my spawn point.

```
    public string spawnPointName;
    public GameObject malePlayerSystems;
    public GameObject femalePlayerSystems;
    public GameObject playerInScene;
    public Transform spawnPoint;
    private Transform playerObject;
    public Vector3 spawnPointPosition;

    public bool inGame = false;
    public bool maleKnight = false;
    public bool femaleKnight = false;
    public bool spawnRunning;
    public bool moveRunning;

    public IEnumerator SpawnPlayer()
    {
        spawnRunning = true;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
        if (spawnRunning)
        {
            spawnPoint = GameObject.Find(spawnPointName).transform;
            //playerInScene = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Gameplay Systems");
            if (playerInScene != null)
            {
                spawnRunning = false;
                yield return null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (maleKnight && !femaleKnight)
                {
                    Instantiate(malePlayerSystems, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    playerInScene = malePlayerSystems;
                    playerObject = malePlayerSystems.transform.Find("Player1/Player Base");
                    playerObjectCC = playerObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
                }

                if (femaleKnight && !maleKnight)
                {
                    Instantiate(femalePlayerSystems, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    playerInScene = femalePlayerSystems;
                    playerObject = femalePlayerSystems.transform.Find("Player1/Player Base");
                    playerObjectCC = playerObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
                }

                if (maleKnight && femaleKnight)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Error: Both gender switches active. Choose one gender to play as.");
                }
            }
            spawnRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public void DestroyPlayer()
    {
        playerInScene = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Gameplay Systems");
        if (playerInScene != null)
        {
            Destroy(playerInScene);
        } else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error: Cannot find player to delete");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator movePlayer(){
        moveRunning = true;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
        if (moveRunning){
            spawnPoint = GameObject.Find(spawnPointName).transform;
            spawnPointPosition = spawnPoint.transform.position;
            playerObjectCC.enabled = false;
            Debug.Log("Disabled CC");
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
            playerObject.transform.position = new Vector3(spawnPointPosition.x, spawnPointPosition.y, spawnPointPosition.z);
            Debug.Log("New Position is " + playerObject.transform.position);
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
            playerObjectCC.enabled = true;
            Debug.Log("Re enabled CC");
        }
        moveRunning = false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your prefabs are all based on 0,0,0?

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based calculation instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.